# Disable activities hot corner in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell, activities-overview

How do I disable the activities overview screen from popping up when I hit the top-left corner of my screen in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many extensions which achieve this purpose, for example:

1. [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/)
2. [Activities Configurator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/)